# Are there any of the Children of the Forest left, or are they extinct?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Asking based on the TV show, information from the books welcome as part of any answer:

In the episode "The Door" (S6E5), we see a few of the Children of the Forest defend the outgoing Three-Eyed-Raven. None of the Children present survive that defense.

Are there any other Children in Westeros or were those the only ones?

One aspect of this is whether...

> The Others/White Walkers could be created again by any remaining Children, assuming the White Walkers were all killed in GoT S8E3.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## We Do Not Know

The only Children of the Forest we see in the series are those at the Cave of the Three Eyed Raven and they get wiped out. I would imagine though that these are supposed to be the last Children of the Forest as they were being slaughtered by men.

> **LEAF:** We were at war. We were being slaughtered. Our sacred trees cut down. We needed to defend ourselves.
>
> **BRAN:** From whom?
>
> **LEAF:** From you. From men.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 6 Episode 5, "The Door"</sub>

In the books the cave is said to be filled with thousands of bones but only 3 living Singers (another name for the Children of the Forest) so we can assume that they are dwindling and are almost wiped out.

> The caves were timeless, vast, silent. They were home to more than three score living singers and the bones of thousands dead, and extended far below the hollow hill. "Men should not go wandering in this place," Leaf warned them. "The river you hear is swift and black, and flows down and down to a sunless sea. And there are passages that go even deeper, bottomless pits and sudden shafts, forgotten ways that lead to the very center of the earth. Even my people have not explored them all, and we have lived here for a thousand thousand of your man-years."
>
> <sub>*A Dance with Dragons*, Bran III</sub>

Of course we only know of those we see so there could be other groups of Children out there somewhere but until mentioned I doubt it.

Note that in the books Leaf "walked the world of men" and so there could be some Children still living amongst men in hiding.

> Meera said, "You speak the Common Tongue now."
>
> "For him. The Bran boy. I was born in the time of the dragon, and for two hundred years I walked the world of men, to watch and listen and learn. I might be walking still, but my legs were sore and my heart was weary, so I turned my feet for home."
>
> <sub>*A Dance with Dragons*, Bran II</sub>

Comment: You quote seems to say "three score" living singers, though it is in the past tense. Is there another section focusing on there being three currently surviving (as of that exchange)?

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman there are no particular reason to believe they are dead. TV show is way beyond the books, and there have not been attack such as in the TV show yet

Comment: @Kepotx, in which case "thousands of bones but only 3 living Singers" should read 3 score. Sorry, I didn't quite make my point clear originally.

Comment: **more than** three score, even.

Comment: Still not sure these comments are being clear enough: [A "score" is 20](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/four_score_and_seven_years_ago). If the book said there were "three score" of them, **that's a fancy way of saying roughly 60, not three.** Pretty big difference there.

Comment: "Score" is a count of 20. "three score" is 60 individuals.

Comment: I vaguely recall that in the books, there is a woman/witch on an island (maybe in the god's eye?). I think it was hinted at that she might be a child of the forest? Maybe someone with a better memory knows more.

Comment: https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ghost_of_High_Heart this is the one I meant, aparently she was claimed to be a child of the forest but probably isn't

Comment: @Pallie Yeah think I read about her before but forgot about it for this answer. As it isn't explicit I'll leave it out but nice find!